# How to place two columns of graph on the same page

Tags: graphs

Please I need someone to help me out with this task. I used the code listing below to achieve the graph shown in Figure1.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[numbers, authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.0in,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,top=0.7in,bottom=0.7in,footskip=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    {\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.50cm+2.5cm}
        \centering
        \rotatebox{90}{\makebox[0pt]{{CM Double Differential Cross--section (mb/MeV/sr)}}}
        {\begin{minipage}{10.82cm+1cm}%
            \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics[width=10.82cm]{Figures/sum36ho1.eps}}\ \\
            \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics[width=10.82cm]{Figures/sum36ho2.eps}}\ \\
            \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-1em}{\includegraphics[width=10.82cm]{Figures/sum36ho3.eps}}\ 

            %% use hspace to center the x-axis lable and then add some space at the end for the subfloat labels.
            \vspace*{0.1cm}\hspace*{\fill}{Alpha Particle Energy (MeV)}\hspace*{\fill}%\hspace*{0.5cm}
        \end{minipage}}%
        %\caption{As in Figure~\ref{fig:sum36sn} but for $^{165}$Ho.}
        \caption{}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

What modification can I add to the code to allow me include three more charts so that the graph can look like Figure2.
Thanks in anticipation.

[image: Figure1]
[image: Figure2]

Comment: Remove `\ \\` from the end of includegraphics. Every two images leave a line in-between.

Comment: Put another minipage right after the first one, which contains the other column of graphics. Check that the sum of widths of the minipages does not exceed the allowed `\linewidth`

Comment: Some suggestions: There's no need to encase the `minipage` environments in braces. Don't clutter your code with expressions such as `{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.50cm+2.5cm}`; `{\linewidth}` will do. Finally, don't load `natbib` with both the `numbers` and `authoryear` options. They're mutually exclusive options; the last-mentioned option will "win".

Comment: Thanks so people! I would be very grateful if you can give me the exact codes (that renders properly) that will help me achieve this task as I seem not to get the correct result when I tried your suggestions. You can use the usual dark boxes to represent the plots in the code. Your prompt response is highly needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is simplified code producing the requested output.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0in,margin=0.7in,footskip=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \begin{minipage}{0.95\linewidth}
        \centering
        \rotatebox{90}{\makebox[0pt]{{CM Double Differential
        Cross--section (mb/MeV/sr)}}}
        \newlength{\figwidth}
        \setlength{\figwidth}{0.4\linewidth}
        \begin{minipage}{\figwidth+1cm}%
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=\figwidth]{example-image-a}\\
          \includegraphics[width=\figwidth]{example-image-a}\\
          \includegraphics[width=\figwidth]{example-image-a}\\          
          Alpha Particle Energy (MeV)
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{\figwidth+1cm}%
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=\figwidth]{example-image-b}\\
          \includegraphics[width=\figwidth]{example-image-b}\\
          \includegraphics[width=\figwidth]{example-image-b}\\          
          Beta Particle Energy (MeV)
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{A caption}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Notes:

- I do not have your images so I have used standard ones from the distribution.
- I have introduced a newlength `\figwidth` to hold the desired width of the figures
- All `\raisebox` commands have been removed
- `\centering` has been used for horizontal alignment in each column
- I have assumed the aspect ratio of all your figures is the same
- Dimension expressions have been simplified, and unnecessary nesting of groups removed
- `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so loading the latter is not necessary
- `margin` sets all four margins for `geometry` in one go